# Suspending and resuming VM in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I'm having a recurrent problem while using the Google Cloud Platform. To illustrate what's happening I created a new VM, successfully connected to it via `gcloud beta compute ssh`, and suspended the instance.

After it was suspended, I resumed it, but wasn't able to connect to it via ssh anymore, I ran the command:

`gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "test-vm" --project "my-project" --ssh-flag="-vvv"`

and received the following output:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/guilherme/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "34.66.57.82" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 34.66.57.82 [34.66.57.82] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 34.66.57.82 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 34.66.57.82 port 22: Connection timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

The suspend/resume was done in browser, on GCP's platform.

Because of this problem I have not been able to suspend any VMs, since I "lose" it everytime. Does anyone know how to properly suspend it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a change in the setup "gcloud" denies an ssh connection, you must update the ssh keys in your metadata by:

```
sudo gcloud compute config-ssh
```

If this complains about different entries in your config file where your ssh key entries are stored, ~/.ssh/config, delete this file and execute the above command again.

If the internal firewall of the system block port 22, you can try the following steps to fix it:

1. In the GCP Console, go to the VM Instances.
2. Select the instance and click edit.
3. Find Custom metadata option and Click Add item and Type startup-script as a key and Copy and past the command sudo ufw allow ssh as a value. This command will enabled port 22 for SSH.

Recommend this topic [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) for your issue.

Comment: Adding the start up script really worked! Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome, please accept my anser if it works.